# Regular Expression: Matching letters or letters with numbers only

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to build a regex which can capture:

1. All letter strings, such as 'abc', 'def'
2. Strings with letters and numbers such as '123a', 'a23b', 'df4'

but not to capture pure numbers such as:

1. '123'
2. '123.23'

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: And what have you tried? Do you want to extract all such strings from a longer one? What about white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may looking for this one: `\d*[a-zA-Z]+\d*[a-zA-Z]*`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 import re
    >>> if(re.match(".*[a-z].*",'abc123')):
        print "1"


    1
    >>> if(re.match(".*[a-z].*",'123')):
        print "1"


    >>> if(re.match(".*[a-z].*",'123abc')):
        print "1"


    1
```